# Display mathematical equation in unity3D

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

I want do display mathematical equation in unity using it's GUI system. Is there a way? I am using c# language for programming in Unity. It would be useful for me if I could also display mathematical symobls using c# code. Thanks!

Comment: You just want to display an equation `a + b = c` for example on the screen in Unity? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: I want to display mathematical symbols like radicals and limits etc..

Comment: havent heard anything about this since march, but maybe you'll find something: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/212709/The_Wolfram_Language_will_soon_be_integrated_into_Unity.php

Answer (score 5):

Since 2016, you can use [TEXDraw](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/texdraw-51426) (Paid asset) to render mathematical expressions in unity.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that is not for free!

Answer (score 3):

You can do LaTeX math with a web api and download it as a texture. An example:

[image]

How to use in Unity3d:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Tester : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] string formula=@"\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\;dx=\sqrt{\pi}";
    Texture texture=null;

    IEnumerator Start() {
        WWW www=new WWW("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl="+formula);
        yield return www;
        texture=www.texture;
    }

    void OnGUI() {
        if(texture != null)
            GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0,0,texture.width,texture.height), texture);
    }
}
```

There are many implementations,used here is the [Google Charts API](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/infographics/docs/formulas). Unfortunatly it will be retired in a year or so.

If you don't want google's, an alternative is a custom hosted tex2im.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, but if i use your method, i supose that the user should stay conected to internet while using my game, and that is not what i want.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution and it works even now!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using GUI Text.
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GuiText.html

Here is a decent YouTube tutorial on how to do this.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4nGKxZ7tVA

As for displaying the mathematical symbols you will just format your sting with the symbols in the sting, then display the sting in the GUI Text.

Place the following in a C# script and add the script to the GUIText object then the scene and the text will update.

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = a + b;
guiText.text = String.Format("{0} + {1} = {2}", a, b, c);
```

Comment: Broken Link in Answer