# How can i write math equation inside unity

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I am developing a quiz program using unity ( c#  ) where the program gets the questions from XML files , How can i  add math formulas to the XML file and the math equation is displayed correctly in the program ? i tired to use MathML but unity hasn't recognized it and instead of displaying the equation it displays the commands of MathML, Here is a sample of my code for parsing XML file and load it from resources

```
public string parseXmlFile(string xmlData)
{

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(new StringReader(xmlData));
    string xmlPathPattern = "//data-set/record";
    XmlNodeList myNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xmlPathPattern);
    foreach (XmlNode node in myNodeList)
    {
        XmlNode q1 = node.FirstChild;
        XmlNode an1 = q1.NextSibling;
        XmlNode q2 = an1.NextSibling;
        XmlNode an2 = q2.NextSibling;
        XmlNode q3 = an2.NextSibling;
        XmlNode an3 = q3.NextSibling;

        totValue += q1.InnerXml + "|" + q2.InnerXml + "|" + q3.InnerXml+ "|"+ an1.InnerXml + "|" + an2.InnerXml + "|" + an3.InnerXml + "|"  
          + "/";
 } 
 return totValue;

 }

_xml = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(xmlfile);

    string totval = parseXmlFile(_xml.text);
        totval = totval.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
            allFile = totval.Split('/');
            Text2.text=allfile[0];
```

after that i use allfile elements to display it in text UI

Comment: If you show your code (in a [mcve]), you have a much higher chance of getting a useful answer

Comment: Well you return a `string` there .. not clear how you expect the string to be used later ...

Comment: Look at *Krzysztof Bociurko*'s answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894567/display-mathematical-equation-in-unity3d/41225947#41225947)